# Creating a Branch in Subversion from a specific Trunk Revision

Tags: svn, branch

I am using Versions (Mac OS X SVN software) and have created a branch labeled 3.0

I would like to take everything that is up to revision 144 from our Trunk and basically make that into the branch 3.0.

I have no clue how I am supposed to do that.

Comment: Answer using GUI here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753601/create-branch-in-versions-mac-subversion-client
I can't believe it's so hard to find. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use the `svn copy` command.

```
svn copy my_repo/trunk -r 144 my_repo/branches/3.0
```

or

```
svn copy ^/trunk -r 144 ^/branches/3.0
```

where `^/` is a shortcut for the remote URL.

check [the documentation here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.using.html#svn.branchmerge.using.create)

Comment: Is there a way to do this using the Versions client?

Comment: One think I noticed about this command is the actual folder "trunk" is copied into branch 3.0, is there a way just to get the content inside trunk and not the actual folder copied over?

Comment: try this `svn copy my_repo/trunk/ -r 144 my_repo/branches/3.0`

Comment: With that command you also get local changes. Use ^/ instead to get only files from the server, but no local changes. See documentation. I would therefore say this answer is wrong.

Comment: @Ini : in the answer, the `my_repo` refers to the remote URL, so it will not take the local changes ^_^ , but you're right, using `^/` is the same (and a good shortcut)

Comment: True, I revert my statement, sry. Thank you for incorporating my suggestion in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
 $ svn copy -r 144 URL/trunk URL/branches/Rev3.0
```