# Create branch in Versions (Mac Subversion client)

Tags: macos, versions

I have search everywhere but I can't find information on how to create a branch in Versions for Mac. How is this done?

Comment: Doesn't belong here. This isn't a coding-related question and should be on SU.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Check the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on-topic.

Answer (score 15):

There was very little information on this but I found the answer. Just press Option key and drag the trunk into the branches folder

Comment: @noa, or any folder within your repository where you store your branches.

Comment: @Crashdesk, can you maybe add a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

The option key opens the Move dialog and copies the source to the target, then deletes the source.  You can Duplicate the project first, then option/drag to Move the duplicate to the branches folder.

Answer (score 1):

A branch or tag is simply a copy of the trunk, or in some cases another folder, in your Subversion repository. To create one, use the “Browse” view to navigate to the right place in your repository and drag the trunk of your project to the “branches” folder while holding down the “Option” (alt) key on your keyboard. When you drop the trunk, a dialog will open asking you to name your new tag or branch.

Comment: After copying the trunk to a branch, if you were to look at the history of a file in the branch, would you see the full history of the file going back to before the branch?